# Rails - listing most active profile based on number of posts, comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-postgresql

Profiles can create posts.
Profiles can comment on posts.
Weightage: post = 1, comment = 1.

i need to list people based on consolidated weightage of posts, comments within last month.

what i have tried is:

```
profiles = Profile.find(:all, :include => [:posts, :comments], :conditions => ["posts.created_at > ? or comments.created_at > ?", 1.month.ago, 1.month.ago], :group => "profiles.id", :group => 'profiles.id, posts.id, comments.id', :limit => 5)
```

and

```
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT profiles.id, count(posts.id) + count(comments.id) as pcount FROM profiles LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON posts.profile_id = profiles.id LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON comments.profile_id = profiles.id WHERE (posts.created_at > '#{1.month.ago}' and posts or comments.created_at > '#{1.month.ago}') GROUP BY profiles.id Order by pcount"
profiles = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Comment: You can have two attributes in your profile table, :comments_count & :posts_count, And every time a user writes a post or comment, you can use rails callbacks for incrementing these values.

Comment: In that case we could not read the time of post or comment. I need the last one month's top contributor list.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest we `LEFT JOIN` on both tables conditioned on the `created_at` date and count the total number of non-`NULL` values for each independently as a new field called `total_weight`:

```
profiles = Profile.joins("LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.profile_id = profiles.id AND posts.created_at > ? LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.profile_id = profiles.id AND comments.created_at > ?", 1.month_ago, 1.month_ago).group("profiles.id").select("profiles.*, sum(posts.id IS NOT NULL) + sum(comments.id IS NOT NULL) as total_weight")
```

You can use `"total_weight"` in `order` and `having` clauses, and you can reference it in the results: `profiles.first.total_weight`.

I'd consider using keeping the respective counts or total count in a new column on `profiles` to make this query faster and easier to maintain. You could have a task that runs daily to update it on each profile, that way the controller that has to fetch the records does not have to initiate this computation every time.

Comment: having extra fields will not help in this situation as we consider the time of post/comment.

Comment: So what about doing the join suggested?

Comment: And the point about the extra fields if you have an offline task that runs, say, once a day, to update them. We do this in our app a few places; e.g., update a state column to "hidden" if an object is in a set of other states and not updated for 2 weeks. This way, the query run on our main landing page does not have to compare dates, which is very slow, but instead just compared against an indexed state column which is updated offline.

Answer (score 0):

Create a model `Activities` with columns `month, 'comments_count', 'posts_count','profile_id'` so that,

In your `profile.rb`, you have

```
has_many :activities
```

and `activity.rb`, you have

```
belongs_to :profile
```

At every end of the month using [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever), run a job computing these numbers and adding values for each user.

Pros:

1. You can keep count of all the profile activities per month.
2. This caches your output and simplifies your query drastically. You just need to do: `profile.activities.where(month: Date.today.month - 1.month)`.

PS: You can improve the query

Cons:
1. It will be difficult to maintain as time passes and profile increases.

If you want to just keep a count for last month, This con will be easily solved.